# Cardboard box giving me strange mesh errors

Tags: modeling, modifiers

I'm making a simple cardboard box for a archviz scene and I got these strange results after doing a Boolean operation. I wanted to create a slit where you can place your hands into to pick it up but it's giving me some strange errors like this:

[image]

Here is the blend file:

[image]

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You've shaded smooth your object, so it is trying to smooth between the big faces and the small ones of your bevel, therefore the long triangular shadows we see on the large faces:

[image]

You have several solutions, either you:

- Shade flat
- Give a *Subdivision Surface* to your object so that it has more virtual faces to smooth
- Lower down the *Auto Smooth* value but in that case it won't smooth between the faces of the bevel itself
- Create an inset in the large faces. The new faces that will be created around the inset will be co-planar with the inset, so there won't be any smooth shading between them
- Give a *Weighted Normal* modifier to your object, which will prevent any shade smooth on the big faces (enable its *Keep Sharp* option)

Comment: Thanks for the suggestions. With these I was able to fix the issue, but if you don't mind me asking another question related to the issue. When should we use bevels instead of subdivision surface and vice versa?

Comment: I'm not sure what you mean, you can use both actually

Answer (score 1):

additionally to moonboots answer you could add a plane, R X 90.

[image]

on your cube add a data transfer modifier:

[image]

check "face data", source: plane,  press smooth, hide the plane.

result:

[image]